# Merge two data Sets & filling in mulitple fields based on one column in R

Tags: r, loops, merge, row

Okay So I have two arrays/tables and I'm merging on TIMEDATE.
[image: Long Array]

[image: Long]

I am using this code:

```
Long_LA <- merge(x = LongArray,y = Long,by="TIMEDATE", all.x = TRUE)
```

This is what the two merged together looks like:
[image: After Merge]

Now... I'm trying to fill in Activity code based on "Segment Activity" for X number of rows based on SegmentDuration_Seconds.

I know in excel I'd just fill down and I know the capability exists to do this in R but I can't get it to work.
Is there someone out there that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

this can be done easier using non-equi joins `data.table` package as follows. More explanations inline

```
#create the end timedate as well before non-equi join
Long[, ENDTIMEDATE := STARTTIMEDATE + SEGMENTDURATION_SECONDS]

#non-equi joins
LongArray[Long, Activity_Code := SEGMENTACTIVITY, on=.(TIMEDATE >= STARTTIMEDATE, TIMEDATE <= ENDTIMEDATE)]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
LongArray <- data.table(TIMEDATE=seq(as.POSIXct("2018-02-15"), by="1 min", length.out=14), 
    Order=1:14)
Long <- data.table(STARTTIMEDATE=as.POSIXct("2018-02-15"), SEGMENTACTIVITY=1, SEGMENTDURATION_SECONDS=6300)
```

Comment: can I change the by = "1 min" to "1 second" because this needs to be at the second level

Comment: Also... I got this error with the first code    Error in `:=`(ENDTIMEDATE, STARTTIMEDATE + SEGMENTDURATION_SECONDS) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: Yeah you can change to 1 sec. those tables must be data.tables. You can convert data.frame to data.table using setDT